# setting a const a certain value until its called, using redux-sage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, typescript, redux

Maybe I should explain what Im trying to do, I have  a Search function that display information from an api, I want to have the default value of repos shown to something like "example" so all of examples repos show before you begin any search, however I want the search bar to display Search(the placeholder), I try to do this by changing username to "example" in the following code

```
 import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

 import {
  CHANGE_USERNAME,
 } from './constants';

 // The initial state of the App
 const initialState = fromJS({
  username: 'example', // this makes the search bar have the text example on it
 });

 function homeReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case CHANGE_USERNAME:

  // Delete prefixed '@' from the github username
   return state
    .set('username', action.name.replace(/@/gi, ''));
   default:
     return state;

  }
 }

 export default homeReducer;
```

but It gave the default value of the search bar example too, and you had to erase it in order to make another search.

just going to add more code

```
                   export class HomePage extends  React.PureComponent                                      { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-       stateless-function
                      /**
                           * when initial state artist is not null, submit  the form to  load repos
                     * 
                  */
            componentDidMount() {
              if (this.props.username && this.props.username.trim().length >  0) {
              this.props.onSubmitForm();
                }
         }

        render() {
           const { loading, error, repos } = this.props;
          const reposListProps = {
          loading,
            error,
          repos,
          };

         return (
           <div>
              <Helmet
               title="Home Page"
              meta={[
                  { name: 'description', content: 'Search upcoming concerts  by your favorite Artist' },
                    ]}
              />

              <SearchWrapper>
                <form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmitForm} autoComplete="off">
                   <label htmlFor="username">
                    <InputSearch
                   id="username"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Search"
                 value={this.props.username} 
                onChange={this.props.onChangeUsername} 
                autoComplete="off"
               />
            </label>
          </form>
           <InputIcon>
                <Icon_eyeglass className="material-     icons">search</Icon_eyeglass>
                 </InputIcon>
               </SearchWrapper>
             <ActionBar />
                      {/*ActionBar should be render in App main */}
             <ReposList {...reposListProps} />
          </div>
           );
       }
      }

        HomePage.propTypes = {
          loading: React.PropTypes.bool,
         error: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
           React.PropTypes.object,
       React.PropTypes.bool,
         ]),
        repos: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
        React.PropTypes.array,
         React.PropTypes.bool,
         ]),
          onSubmitForm: React.PropTypes.func,
         username: React.PropTypes.string,
        onChangeUsername: React.PropTypes.func,
       };

      export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
          onChangeUsername: function onChangeUsername(evt) {
          return dispatch(changeUsername(evt.target.value));

          username.value = "";
          },
       onSubmitForm: (evt) => {
         if (evt !== undefined && evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
          dispatch(loadRepos());
      value = "";
        },
        };
       }

      const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
        repos: makeSelectRepos(),
         username: makeSelectUsername(),
        loading: makeSelectLoading(),
      error: makeSelectError(),
       });
```

Comment: don't manipulate your `state`, redux prefers pure functional methods (especially reducers). Return a new state object with all it's properties and a new username (Or at least, this is the way I understand it). As an extra info, I mean your `state.set` statement in the reducer

Comment: Can you show me, Im working on something else and I dont want to spend any more time than I have(full day already) on this problem